# Icons Too Small after Installing Guest Additions iso VirtualBox

Tags: linux, virtualbox, resolution

After I downloaded the Guest Additions CD Image onto my Ubuntu VM on VirtualBox, the screen will change to full screen **but the icons and UI layout are very small**. They do not have the proper size - (height width) ratio. 
As you can see below, there is a large chunk of white space off to the right and below the file icons.

[image: B]

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This is because the screen resolution was increased after guest additions installation. You can try reducing the resolution. Below are steps to change settings.

from https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/look-resolution.html.en

```
Open the Activities overview and start typing Settings.

Click on Settings.

Click Devices in the sidebar.

Click Displays in the sidebar to open the panel.

If you have multiple displays and they are not mirrored, you can have different settings on each display. Select a display in the preview area.

Select the resolution or scale, and choose the orientation.

Click Apply. The new settings will be applied for 20 seconds before reverting back. That way, if you cannot see anything with the new settings, your old settings will be automatically restored. If you are happy with the new settings, click Keep Changes.
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however there is no resolution which matches my laptops, and 100% scale keeps the same issue. Not sure why this doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try higer scales too, say 150% ?